# Too many gem names

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to publish my gem. Looks like I'm having two errors.

> Failed to load /Users//.gemrc because it doesn't contain valid YAML hash
>
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
>
> Too many gem names (/Users//Documents/Projects/Gems/Pirateme/pkg/.gem, Set, to, http://mygemserver.com); please specify only one

Anyone can shine some light to it? Not sure, I restarted the gem a few times.

Comment: The first error is because your `.gemrc` isn't valid YAML (or doesn't contain a YAML hash), just like it says.

Comment: Please include all information in your question which will enable people to provide an answer. What is the contents of `/users/.gemrc`? What is the contents of `.../pkg/.gem`? What command(s) are you running when the error occurs? What is the contents of your `gemspec`? It's better to provide too much information than too little.

Comment: I was running the command rake release, but I just removed the .gemrc file and it worked. Not sure if that was a wise choice and I also update my ruby version to 2.2.3 as well.

Answer (score 4):

I've the same error without any `.gemrc` but I removed those lines from `<my_gem>.gemspec`

```
  # Prevent pushing this gem to RubyGems.org. To allow pushes either set the 'allowed_push_host'
  # to allow pushing to a single host or delete this section to allow pushing to any host.
  if spec.respond_to?(:metadata)
    spec.metadata['allowed_push_host'] = "TODO: Set to 'http://mygemserver.com'"
  else
    raise "RubyGems 2.0 or newer is required to protect against public gem pushes."
  end
```

And it's works

[see this commit](https://github.com/FinalCAD/overlap/commit/e7a8724d1126f96bfdd4675be781c1fbe86b0eda)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late, but maybe this will help someone else. I had the same error and the following change in my `.gemspec` file worked for me. Just needed to specify the push host, since `rake release` is preparing our gem before pushing it (and that second part would be hard without a push location specified).

```
if spec.respond_to?(:metadata)
  spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = 'https://rubygems.org'
else
  raise "RubyGems 2.0 or newer is required to protect against public gem pushes."
end
```